# Xdebug with Docker compose over Atom

Tags: docker, docker-compose, atom-editor, xdebug

I am using Docker compose having PHP and Apache setup as 2 different services. I am using atom as IDE and php-debug extension for debugging.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  httpd:
      image: httpd:latest
      ports:
          - 8080:80
          - 9000:9000
      volumes:
          - ./docker/httpd/conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf
      volumes_from:
          - php
  php:
      build: ./docker/php/
      expose:
          - 9000
      volumes:
          - ./code:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

Dockerfile for PHP

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql json mysqli

# Enable and configure xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_autostart=true' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_mode=req' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_connect_back=0 ' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_port=9000' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_host=172.19.0.1' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_enable=1' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.idekey=xdebug-atom' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_autostart=1' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

php-debug in Atom

```
"php-debug":
    PathMaps: [
      "remotepath;localpath"
      "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs;/Users/shahzadfatehali/Sites/fiddlesoft/mansab/code"
    ]
    ServerPort: 9000
    currentPanelHeight: "259px"
    currentPanelMode: "bottom"
```

When I run PHPDebug in Atom it show me that its listening to `127.0.0.1:9000` but when I access the page on browser I see no breakpoint execution in Atom.

Can anyone identify the misconfiguration here?

Comment: `- 9000:9000` and `expose: - 9000` -- Why? RTM -- it's Xdebug that connects to IDE (Atom) and NOT other way around. You do not need t expose Xdebug port .. because right now port is occupied by Docker .. so Atom is simply unable to listen on that port on host machine...

Comment: I got your point Dan Lowe and I am trying to fix it but another point that confuses me is that how can I start debug session from within Atom as we do in PHPStorm, NetBeans or any other IDE.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE:** I couldn't help to chip-in and contribute, since I've been there.

## The Solution

### Assumptions

- You know your way around PHP, Nginx, Docker, CLI, Linux and Atom.
- You're in development mode and not in production.
- You're development is leveraging the use of *nix (UN*X) like environment.
- You're using Atom as your IDE.
- A dynamic app, at its simplest, your Dockerized project should be configured to provision three (3) containers, i.e.:

  - one serving Nginx Web server,
  - a second, serving PHP-FPM engine
  - a third, serving DB server.
- Your Docker Compose should be configured to use Volumes to bind locally (host) with PHP-FPM container.

### 1 - For Docker PHP-FPM Container

**1.1 - Create locally and edit your xdebug ini file to reflect the following configurations**

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote.mode=req
xdebug.remote.handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug-error.log
```

> *host.docker.internal* value assigned to xdebug.remote_host will ensure Docker to map the correct host IP address.

**1.2 - Configure PHP-FPM Dockerfile to install xdebug, activate the module and copy its config file into the container**

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
...
RUN pecl install -f xdebug \
  docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
...
COPY ./conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

**1.3 - Configure PHP-FPM service in Docker Compose**

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  bridge_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  web_server:
    ...
    networks:
      - bridge_network
    depends_on:
      - app_server
      - db_server

  app_server:
    ...
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ../..:/var/www
    networks:
      - bridge_network
    depends_on:
      - db_server

  db_server:
    ...
    networks:
      - bridge_network
```

### 2 - Atom IDE

**2.1 - Install php-ide**

```
Atom IDE > Preferences/Settings > Install > search php-ide > click install
```

**2.2 - Install language-php**

```
Atom IDE > Preferences/Settings > Install > search language-php > click install
```

**2.3 - Install php-debug**

```
Atom IDE > Preferences/Settings > Install > search php-debug > click install
```

> **IMPORTANT:** Do not define any PathMaps manually. Atom IDE will define it for you.

### 3 - Debugging PHP code

**3.1 - Toggle PHP-Debug + PHP Console panels**

```
Atom IDE > Bottom left corner of the app window > Find two tabs "PHP Debug" and "PHP Console" > Click on one of them > Two panels will open.
```

> **NOTE:** You only need "PHP Debug" and "PHP Console" panels to debug a PHP code, nothing more.

**3.1 - Define Breakpoints**

1. Open a PHP file.
2. Scroll to the target line.
3. Set your breakpoint by pointing and clicking at the left edge of the line.
4. You will see Breakpoints add-up under "PHP Debug" Panel > Breakpoints window.

**3.2 - Attaching Debugger**

1. Open your Internet browser of preference.
2. Navigate to http://localhost:80 which points to Nginx server.
3. Browse the app and head to where the breakpoint supposedly is located.
4. Let page load. Once page loaded.
5. Turn to Atom IDE and you'll see a window pop-up prompting to "save" the Path Maps, which was captured by Atom IDE.
6. You should act quickly and press "Save", since time is limited to react. Otherwise, you'll have to redo by reloading the page.